# Accessing Google Cloud SQL instance from Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-compute-engine

After spending a few hours, this is the only real documentation I can find for accessing Cloud SQL from outside of GAE: https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/external

The problem is, this is for a Java application (via JDBC).

I need to access my Cloud SQL DB from within a PHP, Dart, or NodeJS application. I thought by giving my GCE instance rights to connect to Cloud SQL, this would be easy. But no arrangement of socket strings (using mysql drivers) seems to be effective.

For argument's sake, let's say I'm trying to connect with a PHP app. My mysql connection array looks like this:

```
(
  'driver'    => 'mysql',
  'unix_socket'     => '/cloudsql/project-id:instance-id',
  'host'      => 'localhost',
  'database'  => 'dbname',
  'username'  => 'root',
  'password'  => '',
  'charset'   => 'utf8',
  'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
  'prefix'    => '',
)
```

This is as close as I got, but I'll get a generic "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket" error.

Answer (score 1):

While this is an older question, I just thought I should share what I've found in regards to this.

First off, you were attempting to connect to a MySQL Server on your GCE instance, not your remote CloudSQL instance.

To begin

1. Go into your dashboard and request an IP for your CloudSQL Instance.
2. Go to CloudSQL Access Control and add your GCE IP address.
3. Connect to CloudSQL from GCE via mysql-client and add a new (non-root) user
4. Use the CloudSQL IP and the new non-root user to access CloudSQL from GCE PHP files.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud SQL team are working on improving the connectivity from Compute Engine. If you send this question to google-cloud-sql-discuss@googlegroups.com, they will be able to follow up.

Comment: Hey @JoeFaith thanks. Looking forward to it. I often have conference calls and such with people on your Cloud teams, always very helpful. If I get any kind of answer or some kind of work-around, I'll be sure to post answer here if able.

Edit: not having much luck with that address-

Comment: Edit: not having much luck with that address-
"We're writing to let you know that the group you tried to contact (google-cloud-sql-discuss) may not exist, or you may not have permission to post messages to the group."

Comment: I think you will need to join the group first before you can post to it. Visit https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-sql-discuss

Answer (score 0):

You could connect indirectly I.E. Create a Java-based App Engine App that provides an interface to the database for you, and consume that interface from your PHP app?

For example: Java App Engine App has a 'getEmployees' method call that calls a Select query on the DB and then formats and returns the results as a JSON file. Your PHP app would then call this method and consume the JSON...

Comment: This is completely over-complicated and unnecessary. All they have to do is add a new non-root user to their GCSQL instance and connect using their GCSQL IP+that user instead of localhost+root